# Expected identifier error IE8 using e.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a need to support IE8 and I have a problem with this piece of code:

```
$('#lightboxWrapper').live("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.class != 'lightboxContent' && !$('.lightboxContent').find(e.target).length) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hideLightbox();
    }
});
```

I'm getting an "Expected identifier" error on IE8 on the 2nd line and not sure how to fix it.

We're using this to allow customers to click 'outside' of a lightbox area to close the lightbox without the need to click on the 'close' button.  Works in every other browser and IE9 and above...

Used http://caniuse.com/#search=Target to check the 'target' but not sure if I'm reading this incorrectly?!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What version of jQuery are you working with? `live()` has been deprecated for many years now. Also note that `e !==event` in many browsers

Comment: Hi, we are using 1.9.1, but we have another function above using the same live() and that seems to be working OK ... ?

Comment: Then you must be using a migrate plugin because `live()` was removed from API as of 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/live/  Try using `on()`. Can also simplify the `if` using `if(!$(e.target).closest('.lightboxContent').length)`

Comment: Isn't closest not supported in IE?

Comment: It is supported cross browser as are all jQuery methods

Comment: Did you mean to use e.preventDefault()?